# Unit/Mock testing with Paypal REST SDK best practices

Tags: java, unit-testing, paypal, mockito, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm developing an application using the [Paypal REST SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/) for Java.  I'm trying to develop tests for my application.  The thing is, the development pattern suggested by Paypal in [their documentation for the functionality I'm trying to use](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/capture-payment/#set-up-the-authorization-information-object) is very counterproductive to allowing stubbing and hooking for unit tests.  I'd prefer not to make all of the Paypal API structs parameters to my method, because that would bloat my method signature, but I'd like to be able to test my code.  What are some best practices or solutions others use to test applications with Paypal REST SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good question, however I fail to see how their API can be counterproductive for your testing strategy. Is there any specific coding problem you have; then add that code to your question.

In general you want to isolate all handing of 3-paty integration to a small part of your system (there is no need to use their classes in your own method signatures); then you can mock that part of the system if/when needed. And if you want to you can test that you have a correct integration in isolation (probably by mocking the protocol).

Comment: Using Mockito, I'd like to check things like, for example, the parameters of the payment request matches the parameters I'm expecting, the data structures that are being set up are the ones that I'm expecting to be set up, etc.  However, in the tutorial provided (linked in OP), the Payment object is created inside the method, so mocking it (so I can check and verify its contents in a unit test) is not possible.  Is there another best practice I should be using?

Comment: For the purposes of this discussion, you may assume my code matches the tutorial code.  I've more or less copy-pasted from the tutorial, although I've added a couple additional fields to my Payment object.  All the "business logic", as it were, is the exact same as the tutorial.